# Trouble displaying Cell Date in swift, No errors

Tags: uitableview, swift, cell

ok so basically setting a basic messaging app using parse, have my message controller here finished but the cell data just isn't displaying. Im not getting any errors so not much to go on. Can anyone with a fresh pair of eyes spot the error code is as follows :-

```
class MessagesTableViewController: UITableViewController {
var messages = []

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    messages = []
    self.navigationController?.title = "My Messages"
    var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
    var query = PFQuery(className: "toUser")
    query.whereKey("toUser", equalTo: currentUser!)
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (results: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            self.messages = results!
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return messages.count > 0 ? 1 : 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messages.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    let messageDate = messages[indexPath.row].valueForKey("createdAt") as! NSDate
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyy hh:mm:ss"
    let strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(messageDate)
    let message: String = messages[indexPath.row].valueForKey("message") as! String
    let fromUser: String = messages[indexPath.row].valueForKey("fromUser") as! String
    cell.textLabel?.text = message
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "From \(fromUser) : \(strDate) "
    return cell
}

}
```

any ideas?
thanks

Comment: Put this statement `self.tableView.reloadData()` like this `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})` in `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`

Comment: hi unfortunately still doesn't display the Cell data. Real head scratcher this one the code is compiling without issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well just goes to show looking at code to long hurts your eyes! the data wasn't pulling through because of one simple mistake

this line :-

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "message")
```

I originally had it set to

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "toUser")
```

wrong table name within my data

thanks to all who looked at this

Answer (score 0):

i have tried like this , it's no matter on reload the dataSource.It may be the problem of data ,I think.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    swift_dispatch_after(2, { () -> () in
        self.array = NSArray(objects:"a","bb","vcc")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    });
}

// MARK: - Table view data source
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    if array.count != 0 {
      let messageDate = NSDate()
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyy hh:mm:ss"
        let strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(messageDate)

        cell.textLabel?.text = (array[indexPath.row] as! String) + strDate
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: thanks, so you think it could be the way its pulling the info from the database?

Comment: sorry not sure sure what you mean here  this code doesn't help at all as you have changed the format and the cell data isn't correct

Comment: i've use `swift_dispatch_after` to Simulation the request callBack to proof the reload works well. So, I think it might the problem of database.